# A bit of confusion with central idea of "running" coupling constants

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory

An effective quantum field theory of a single scalar field $\phi$ is described by an action, $S(\phi,\{g_n\})$ where $\{g_n\}$ denote the coupling constants of the theory. The corresponding path-integral $$Z=\int\mathcal{D}\phi\exp[iS]$$ is usually defined with a finite UV cut-off $\Lambda$. When the cut-off is lowered from the scale $\Lambda$ to $\Lambda^\prime=\frac{\Lambda}{b}$ ($b> 1$) by integrating out the fast Fourier components with momenta between $\Lambda^\prime$ and $\Lambda$, we obtain another lower energy effective action, $$S^\prime(\phi,\{g^\prime_n(\Lambda, \Lambda^\prime)\}).$$ So far, I have tried not to be notationally inconsistent or incomplete. Assuming the description above is all fine, I can understand that the coupling constants will "run" with the lowering of the cut-off. The coupling constants $\{g_n\}$s of the old effective theory (with cut-off $\Lambda$) will change into $\{g_n^\prime\}(\Lambda,\Lambda^\prime)$s for the new effective theory (with the lower cut-off $\Lambda^\prime$). Please correct me for mistakes.

Now consider the initial effective theory $S(\phi,\{g_n\})$ with the **fixed** cut-off $\Lambda$. By **fixed** I mean, unlike the description given above, now I am neither interested in lowering the cut-off $\Lambda$ nor interested in finding a lower energy effective theory. Instead, if I am interested in finding how the coupling constants $\{g_n\}$ of my old theory (with the fixed cut-off $\Lambda$) vary with energy $E$ in the range $0<E<\Lambda$. How should I proceed and what do I expect?

Comment: Are you perhaps asking about the difference between running couplings in Wilsonian RG and continuum RG?

Comment: I don't think I understand the difference. Didn't I sketch the Wilsonian idea? If so, doesn't it work for continuum field theories? I am poor at this.

Answer (score 6):

If you fix the cutoff, in a certain sense, the coupling constants don't run. But it's better to talk about concrete things to it's clear what's going on.

#### Fix parameters in the Lagrangian

If you define $g_i$ to be the parameters that you have in the Lagrangian at a certain cutoff $\Lambda$, then no, they do not depend on the energy of your experiment. Those are fixed once and for all.

#### Define a coupling as a physical correlator

A coupling constant may be defined as the value of an $n$-point correlator at a certain energy $E_0$. More precisely, say you have a three-point coupling $g\,\phi^3(x)$, you can define $g$ as
$$
g = \langle \phi(p_1)\phi(p_2)\phi(p_3)\rangle\big|_{|p_1|=2|p_2|=2|p_3|=E_0}\,,
\tag{1}$$
or something like that. So again, if you fix $E_0$ to a value that you like, $g$ doesn't run. What's true is that the tree-point correlator written above depends nontrivially on the energy $E_0$. Which is not surprising at all. But if $E_0$ is fixed, of course it's constant.

In even more concrete terms: if you compute an amplitude $\mathcal{A}(g,E)$ at energy $E$, and then you compute the same amplitude $\mathcal{A}(g,E')$ at higher energy $E'$, the $g$ that goes in is the same number.

#### So why does the *coupling* run?

Saying that the coupling remains unchanged is kind of moot, precisely because you can choose at what scale to define it. That means that the value of $g$ itself tells you literally nothing about the physics.

What matters for the physics at energy $E$ are the values of the correlators around the same energy scale. So if someone asks you "is this theory strongly coupled?" or "is this theory close to a free theory?" you might want to look at the correlators at those energy scales.

So, for any computations, even at $10^{10^{10}}\,\mathrm{GeV}$, you can keep you coupling defined at the scale $10\,\mathrm{eV}$ and get the correct value. But the physics of the quantum system is more transparent if you redefine $g$ to be $g$ in $(1)$ at the scale of $E_0=10^{10^{10}}\,\mathrm{GeV}$. For instace, some theories are asymptotically free. But, if you fix $g$ at low energies, $g$ is order one and the amplitudes that you compute with it are close to a free theory when $E$ is big.${}^1$ That's kind of perverse.

So it's not the coupling itself that runs, is that we force ourselves to redefine it into a sensible energy range so that there is some meaning attached to it.

---

<sup>$\;{}^1$Nevermind that in real life you won't be able to make a computation with a large coupling because we can deal with QFT only by using perturbation theory, for most situations. For the purpose of this answer, assume that we are all-powerful and can compute all sorts of stuff.</sup>

Comment: Okay. So the idea is to necessarily vary the cut-off. In that case, I think two viewpoints could be taken. Instead of thinking of $\Lambda^\prime$ as the new cut-off of a new theory, one can think of it as an intermediate energy scale between $0$ and $\Lambda$ for the same theory. Alternatively, one can also pretend that as I change the cut-off, the couplings vary and hence, I get a space of theories/Lagrangian. Are both these viewpoints legit?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.